# is_valid() throw exception when a simple form is invalid in django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

When the submitted Form is valid there is no problem but when the submitted Form is invalid(In our case It is blank for example) then the is_valid() throw this exception:
(as I know is_valid() must return false in this situation)

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/sign-up

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 3.3.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'employer',
 'employee',
 'home',
 'admin',
 'django.contrib.admin')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Sina-PC\PycharmProjects\ـ\home\views.py" in sign_up
  32.         if  myForm.is_valid():
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  129.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  121.             self.full_clean()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  273.         self._clean_fields()
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_fields
  288.                     value = field.clean(value)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py" in clean
  149.         self.validate(value)
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py" in validate
  125.             raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'], code='required')

Exception Type: TypeError at /home/sign-up
Exception Value: string indices must be integers
```

my form is :

```
 __author__ = 'Sina-PC'

 from django import  forms

 class SignupForm(forms.Form):
     username=forms.CharField(max_length=10,widget=forms.TextInput);
     username.label='نام کاربری';
     username.required=True;
     username.error_messages="kkkkkk";
```

my view function is :

```
    def sign_up(request):

        if (request.method=="POST"):
            myForm=SignupForm(request.POST);
            if  myForm.is_valid():
                print("do");
                return  render(request,'home/signup-success.html',{'form':myForm});

        myForm=SignupForm();
        return  render(request,'home/sign-up.html',{'form':myForm});
```

and my template is :

```
 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'sign-up' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div id="form1" >

                        {{ form.as_p }}

                         </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left " style="font-family: tahoma" id="registerBt"   >
مرحله بعد
                            </button>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </form>
```

EDIT:Full trace back added.

Comment: please post the full traceback

Comment: you dont need `;` at the end of each line in python

Comment: @sk1p I added full Traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line: `username.error_messages="kkkkkk"`. `error_messages` needs to be a `dict`, like this:

```
username.error_messages = {'required': 'username is required'}
```

Comment: Thank you.I will accept your answer in 7 minute.but just a question.what is the purpose of keys in this dictionary?

Comment: `error_messages` is a dictionary with multiple keys, because some fields need different error messages, depending on the error case. For an example, look at [the `DecimalField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L297). In this case, you actually only need the `'required'` key, because that's the only one used by the `CharField`.